# Prove $g(z) = (\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})+i(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})$holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Knowing that $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ is holomorphic where $z = x + iy$, I am trying to prove that $g(z) = (\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})+i(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})$ is holomorphic. I tried applying the chain rule derivative directly to $g(z)$ to check that the Cauchy-Riemann equations apply, but no luck there since the derivatives didn't match.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: In the real part of $g$, did you mean to have a $v$ perhaps? You currently have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Perhaps you meant $g(z) = (\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} {\color{red}-\frac{\partial {\color{red}v}}{\partial {\color{red}x}} })+i(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})=U+iV$
> > It only remains to verify CR-equations for $g(z)$ viz. $U_x=V_y$ and $U_y=-V_x$.

Use analyticity of $f=u+iv$ and its consequences like $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0, v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$........(*) 
along with $u_{xy}=u_{yx}, v_{xy}=v_{yx}$ .......(**)
Observe that $U_x=u_{xy}-v_{xx}$ and $V_y=u_{yx}+v_{yy}$ are equal by virtue of $(*)$ and $(**)$. Similarly $U_y=u_{yy}-v_{yx}$ and $-V_x=-u_{xx}-v_{xy}$ by $(*) $ and $(**)$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your calculation is mistaken. If $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, then since C-R condition holds, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
In that case, you may want to prove that
$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}  \color{red} +  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)+ i\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right)$$
is holomorphic.
Note that the real part is $2\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$, not $0$.

In fact, the equation above equals to $2i \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$, which is indeed holomorphic.